# I get data through API but unable to use (show it) properly in ReactJS using useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, datatables

I am new to ReactJS,
I fetch(get) data from mongodb [Postman get check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDzCC.png)

I want to display data in table form and using [datatable](https://datatables.net/) using reactJS,

i think `users` in useState does not have data even after i set this `setUsers(data.usersData)`
but in first useEffect() function `console.log(data, "userData");` I get the data while I think `console.log(users)` shows empty array first which i unable to use map() function (in JSX) it properly.

**React Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "datatables.net";

import UserData from "./UserData";

const UsersData = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("_URL_HERE", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data, "userData");
        setUsers(data.usersData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  console.log(users);

  useEffect(() => {
    const table = $("#user-table").DataTable({
      data: users,
      columns: [
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "age_sex" },
        { data: "mobileNumber" },
        { data: "address" },
        { data: "govtId" },
        { data: "guardianName" },
        { data: "nationality" },
      ],
      columnDefs: [{ defaultContent: "-", targets: "_all" }],
    });

    return () => {
      table.destroy();
    };
  }, [users]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <table id="user-table" className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age/Sex</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Govt ID</th>
            <th>Guardian Details</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {/* <UserData users={users} /> */}
          {users.map((user) => {
            return (
              <tr key={user._id}>
                <td>{user.personalDetail.name}</td>
                <td>{`${user.personalDetail.age}/${user.personalDetail.sex}`}</td>
                <td>{user.personalDetail.mobileNumber}</td>
                <td>{user.addressDetail.address}</td>
                <td>{user.personalDetail.govtId}</td>
                <td>{user.contactDetail.guardianName}</td>
                <td>{user.otherDetail.nationality}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsersData;
```

**some screenshot**

here this line console outupt is
        `console.log(data, "userData");`

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR428.png)

when add   `console.log(users);`   too so [output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIPCG.png)

I want my table to shown like this [output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG7u4.png) -Not the  - thing in first 4 rows (but in the field which is empty like missing in last row)-

this thing i get like  passing in `DataTable() data: data.usersData`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("_URL_HERE", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data, "userData");
        setUsers(data.usersData);
        const table = $("#user-table").DataTable({
          data: data.usersData,
          columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "age_sex" },
            { data: "mobileNumber" },
            { data: "address" },
            { data: "govtId" },
            { data: "guardianName" },
            { data: "nationality" },
          ],
          columnDefs: [{ defaultContent: "-", targets: "_all" }],
        });

        return () => {
          table.destroy();
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);
```

but data now showing after I search something [output4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv6YZ.png)